# Child Node set to 0

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, json.net

I am encountering a weird issue that I am not sure how to resolve. The issue I am encountering is when I update a single node in the firebase realtime database, another node that has an integer value is also updated and set to 0.

[image: Child Node effected].

I also tried the following approach in my User Class so that the child node does not update when targeting other values. This does work when updating other values and the age value in the realtime database. However, when I attempt to upload a new user, the child node age is not uploaded to the realtime database.

```
public int? age;
```

The following code is my approach to update the realtime database using JSON.Net.

```
public static void UpdateUserInfo(string userId, string nodeUpdate, string valueUpte, UpdateUserInfoCallback callback)
{
    User user = new User();
    user.email = valueUpte;
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

    Debug.Log("UpdateUserInfo Method");
    var updateRequest = new RequestHelper {
        Uri = $"{databaseURL}users/{userId}.json",
        Method = "PATCH",
        ContentType = "application/json-path+json"
    };

    updateRequest.BodyString = json;
    RestClient.Request(updateRequest).Then(response => {
                   EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Status", response.StatusCode.ToString(), "Ok");
               }).Catch(err =>
               {
                   var error = err as RequestException;
                   EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Error Response", error.Response, "Ok");
               });
}
```

Also here is my user class:

```
 [Serializable] // This makes the class able to be serialized into a JSON
public class User
{
    public string name;
    public string userName;
    public string team;
    public string pswrd;
    public string email;
    public string birthDate;
    public int age;
    public User(string name, string userName, string team, string pswrd, string email, string birthDate, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.team = team;
        this.pswrd = pswrd;
        this.email = email;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public User(){
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach? Or am I missing something that needs to be added? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion that can assist with the issue I am encountering